# Getting an error message when installing psych package

Tags: r, psych

The message I get:
Installing `psych`:

```r
Installing package into 'C:/.../Documents/R/win-library/4.0'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
psych  2.1.9  2.2.3             FALSE

installing the source package 'psych'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/psych_2.2.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1928530 bytes (1.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.8 MB

* installing *source* package 'psych' ...
** package 'psych' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: unexpected symbol in "tools:::makeLazyLoading("psych", 'C:..."
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'psych'
* removing '.../Documents/R/win-library/4.0/psych'

The downloaded source packages are in
    'C:...Temp\Rtmpe405Ws\downloaded_packages'


<U+2714> Package 'psych' successfully installed.
Warning message:
In utils::install.packages("psych", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package 'psych' had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: The code probably doesn't like how you named your directory `C:/Users/Shreya's`, try to rename it by deleting the `'`. Better avoid using special characters for directories and files in future.

Comment: If you are using Windows operating system, you also need to install Rtools. Have you installed it? Apart from installing, you also need to put it in the path variable.